# scheduling a HBase Hadoop MR job having input parameters

Tags: hadoop, hbase, oozie

I am able to run the job using hadoop jar command.
But when I try to schedule the job using oozie I am unable to do that.
Also please let me know if the error is due to data in hbase table or due to xml file.

The WorkFlow xml File is as follows :

```xml
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.1" name="java-main-wf">
    <start to="java-node"/>
    <action name="java-node">

       <java>
               <job-tracker>00.00.00.116:00000</job-tracker>
            <name-node>hdfs://00.00.000.116:00000</name-node>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                    <value>${queueName}</value>
                </property>
            <property>
                <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
                <value>2181</value>
                </property>
            <property>
                <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
                <value>aaaaaa0000002d:2888:3888,bbbbbb000000d:2888:3888,bbbbbb000000d:2888:3888</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                 <name>hbase.master</name>
                  <value>aaaaaa000000d:60000</value>
             </property>

            <property>
                 <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
                 <value>hdfs://aaaa000000d:54310/hbase</value>
            </property>

            </configuration>
             <main-class>com.cf.mapreduce.nord.GetSuggestedItemsForViewsCarts</main-class>
                   </java> 



<map-reduce>
            <job-tracker>1000.0000.00.000</job-tracker>
            <name-node>hdfs://10.00.000.000:00000</name-node>

            <configuration>

    <property>
          <name>mapred.mapper.new-api</name>
          <value>true</value>
        </property>
        <property>
          <name>mapred.reducer.new-api</name>
          <value>true</value>
        </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                    <value>${queueName}</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapreduce.map.class</name>
                    <value>mahout.cf.mapreduce.nord.GetSuggestedItemsForViewsCarts$GetSuggestedItemsForViewsCartsMapper</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapreduce.reduce.class</name>
                    <value>mahout.cf.mapreduce.nord.GetSuggestedItemsForViewsCarts$GetSuggestedItemsForViewsCartsReducer</value>
                </property>

        <property>
            <name>hbase.mapreduce.inputtable</name>
            <value>${MAPPER_INPUT_TABLE}</value>
        </property>

        <property>
            <name>hbase.mapreduce.scan</name>
            <value>${wf:actionData('get-scanner')['scan']}</value>
        </property> 

        <property>
            <name>mapreduce.inputformat.class</name>
            <value>org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat</value>
        </property>
        <property>
        <name>mapreduce.outputformat.class</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.NullOutputFormat</value>
        </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.map.tasks</name>
                    <value>1</value>
                </property>
             <property>
                    <name>mapred.reduce.tasks</name>
                    <value>10</value>
                </property>
<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
<value>2181</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
<value>aaa000,aaaa0000,aaaa00000</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>hbase.master</name>
     <value>blrkec242032d:60000</value>
   </property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
  <value>hdfs://aaaa0000:00010/hbase</value>
</property>





            </configuration>


        </map-reduce>
```

and the error log of mapper is :

```
    Submitting Oozie action Map-Reduce job   
     <<< Invocation of Main class completed <<<        
    Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.MapReduceMain], main() threw exception, No table was provided.
    java.io.IOException: No table was provided.     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase.getSplits(TableInputFormatBase.java:130)          at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java:962)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:979)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$500(JobClient.java:170)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:891)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:844)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1232)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:844)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:818)
    org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.MapReduceMain.submitJob(MapReduceMain.java:91)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.MapReduceMain.run(MapReduceMain.java:57)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:37)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.MapReduceMain.main(MapReduceMain.java:40)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
     org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:454)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:393)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:327)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:270)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1232)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:264)

    Oozie Launcher failed, finishing Hadoop job gracefully          
    Oozie Launcher ends    
    syslog logs    
    2012-12-11 10:21:18,472 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).
    2012-12-11 10:21:18,586 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes.toBytes(Bytes.java:404)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:153)        org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat.setConf(TableInputFormat.java:91)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:70)          at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:130)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java:959)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:979)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$500(JobClient.java:170)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:891)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:844)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1232)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:844)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:818)         at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.MapReduceMain.submitJob(MapReduceMain.java:91)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.MapReduceMain.run(MapReduceMain.java:57)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:37)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.MapReduceMain.main(MapReduceMain.java:40)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)         at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:454)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:393)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:327)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:270)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1232)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:264)
```

Comment: Yeap, the error is because you are not providing a table to scan over. The Input format you're using expects the `mapred.input.files` to be set. How are you running your job manually?

Comment: The job can easily be run by giving the command :
hadoop jar aham-mapreduce-core-1.02-SNAPSHOT-job.jar mahout.cf.mapreduce.nord.GetSuggestedItemsForViewsCarts -start 101p -stop 105p

The table is set in the job itself

TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(TABLE_CUSTOMER_INFO, scan, GetSuggestedItemsForViewsCartsMapper.class, ImmutableBytesWritable.class, MapWritable.class, job);

TableMapReduceUtil.initTableReducerJob(TABLE_CUSTOMER_INFO, GetSuggestedItemsForViewsCartsReducer.class, job);

Comment: I have also tried to schedule job using <mapreduce> Tag , specifying the table name in xml file 


                                                                 <property>
                     <name>hbase.mapreduce.inputtable</name>
                     <value>${MAPPER_INPUT_TABLE}</value>
              </property>


                               And the value of variable is in job.property :

                                                 MAPPER_INPUT_TABLE=CUSTOMER_INFO


but the error is same

Answer (score 1):

When you call `TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapper(..)`, the utility method is configuring a number of job properties, one of which is the HBase table to scan.

Looking through the code ([@GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/org.apache.hbase/hbase/0.89.20100924-28/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/TableMapReduceUtil.java#TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob%28java.lang.String,org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan,java.lang.Class,java.lang.Class,java.lang.Class,org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job%29)), i can see the following properties being set by this method:

```
<property>
  <name>hbase.mapreduce.inputtable</name>
  <value>CUSTOMER_INFO</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hbase.mapreduce.scan</name>
  <value>...</value>
</property>
```

The input table should be the name of your table, the scan property is some serialization of the scan information (a Base 64 encoded version). You best bet in my opinion is to run a job manually, and inspect the job.xml via the job tracker to see what the set values are.

Note you'll also need to set the properties for the reducer (see the source in the [initTableReducerJob method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/org.apache.hbase/hbase/0.89.20100924-28/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/TableMapReduceUtil.java#TableMapReduceUtil.initTableReducerJob%28java.lang.String,java.lang.Class,org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job,java.lang.Class,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String%29)), again inspecting the job.xml for a job that has been submitted manually may be your best bet.

Comment: This was also useless.

<property>
   <name>hbase.mapreduce.inputtable</name>
   <value>${MAPPER_INPUT_TABLE}</value>
  </property>
   
  <property>
   <name>hbase.mapreduce.scan</name>
   <value>${wf:actionData('get-scanner')['scan']}</value>
  </property> 

  <property>
   <name>mapreduce.inputformat.class</name>
   <value>org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat</value>
  </property>

Comment: 'Useless' in what sense - help us to help you! Pastebin your entire workflow.xml, properties file and command line invocation

Comment: useless means - it is also giving the same error , no change in error even after defining the table name.

Comment: Are you still using a custom java action (`com.cf.mapreduce.nord.GetSuggestedItemsForViewsCarts`) or map-reduce action? The custom java action needs to load the defined configuration properties from a file - oozie-action.conf.xml - see http://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.2.7_Java_Action